# How can we check a file content on console in windows?

Tags: windows-xp

How can we check a file content on console in windows?
I have a number of `.cpp` and `.h` files in a project. I am not able to switch from one function to another. For locating functions I am using `findstr`. I am using `EditPlus` to read files. And now it is a headache to open so many editor windows.

Now I want to know Is there any command like `cat` in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `type <filename>` command

Comment: Or use MORE if you want to page per screen http://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm

Comment: Totally forgot about that bad boy :)